# Otree save static results page

Tags: django, otree

I am using OTree to run a number of different app/games/experiments in a session. 
Currently the results of each app is displayed within the app as the last page. But I wish to hold of displaying any results until after all apps have been run, in a final results app.

Rather than having to create a heap of new participant vars to store the all results and write new code to display them, I was hoping that there was some way that within each app, I could save the results_page.html as a static html page (with all variables displayed at their current values not {{variable}} ) that I could load up later outside of the app at the end in a final results app.

I've learnt a fair bit about coding in Otree in the last few months and can understand basic Python, but Django still baffles me (I'm old school).

I've found code to read in a html page and save it as a string, but seems not be able to give the value of variables just {{variable}}. I think I saw something about Django module Bakery?

I was hoping it might be something easy (who doesn't).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Blackers

Answer (score 0):

To be sincere I find this static approach to retrieve players' data from other apps very inefficient.

What I would suggest if you don't want to write a bunch of `participant.vars` is to get the data directly.

If there is a set of apps in your `app_sequence` you can get this data at any moment using participant object and related object manager.

Let say you have apps `['app1', 'app2', 'app3', 'conclusion']`.

Then for any participant when you are in `conclusion` you can get all players from, say, `app2`, by:

```
app2players = self.participant.app2_player.all()
```

then you can summarize any fields of this set of players, or whatever.
For instance this one will show you the summarized payoffs in app in a sequence:

```
def creating_session(self):
    appseqs = [i.lower() for i in self.session.config['app_sequence']]
    for p in self.session.get_participants():
        for i in appseqs:
            player_app_name = '{}_player'.format(i)
            payoff = sum([j.payoff for j in  getattr(p,player_app_name ).all()])
            print('Payoff in app {} for the participant {}:: {}'.format(i, p.code, payoff))
```

the output will be:

```
Payoff in app trial_ch_uh for the participant ujngvqql:: 0 points
Payoff in app treatment_ch_uh for the participant ujngvqql:: 0 points
Payoff in app treatment_repeated_ch_uh for the participant ujngvqql:: 0 points
```

It's a stupid example because I calculate it in `creating_session` when there is no payoff yet, but that's just to illustrate the idea